# Redirect for wordpress permalink

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to change the WordPress permalink structure in `.htaccess` from `/%postname%/` to `/%category%/%postname%/` any suggestions?

Comment: And have you tried doing that on the `WP-ADMIN > MENU > Settings > Permalink` by checking the `Custom Structure`, placing that inside and saving it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yup ditto what Prix said. The WordPress permalink structure rewriting is done internally with php code. Rewriting is done in the root .htaccess file, but permalink structures are handled internally by WordPress. When you save WordPress Permalinks an .htaccess file will be automatically created in your website root folder. The internal Permalink structure rewriting done by WordPress relies on this root .htaccess file in order to correctly perform rewriting.

Permalink Structure Tags are not used in .htaccess code or files and are an internal rewriting feature of WordPress. Or in other words, simply that Permalink Structure Tags are not used in .htaccess code or files.

Comment: Forgot to tell you that I'll be using the permalink structure in wp, but I need to do a 301 redirect from /%postname%/ to /%category%/%postname%/ in .htaccess in order to maintain the link juice

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://yoast.com/change-wordpress-permalink-structure/

Look for the orange "generator" button, it does the job for you.

Comment: That only redirects to /%postname%/, the opposite of the question!

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong, inside the settings on the "permalink" voice you can modify this last one.

Just remember to put the correct .htaccess inside your website:

https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

Usually to use correctly the permalink you have to use %postname% on the personalized structure.